# Problem on Matrix Calculus

Tags: calculus, matrices, tensor-products

I have been reading a paper lately (doi:10.1109/TAC.2019.2946231). It said that,

"Function $V(X):\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^2$. Lemma 1 shows that $\nabla^2V(I)\cdot v^{\vert\vert}=0$, where $v^{\vert\vert}$ can be seen as a skew-symmetric matrix."

My question is that $\nabla^2V(I)$ is a fourth-order tensor, and the operator "$\cdot$" is not defined in the article. Could you please clarify what operation it should represent?

The article shows an example, $V(X)=\frac{1}{4}\Vert X^{T}X-I\Vert$, I have computed its $\nabla^2V(I)=2*I_3 \otimes I_3$. However, when I used https://www.matrixcalculus.org/ to compute the result, I was told that it could not be expressed in matrix form. So I wonder if is this correct, and how can I verify that it satisfies the Lemma 1?